# Homography estimation from consecutive video frame lines gives bad results

Tags: image-processing, geometry, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to build a program which detects offside situation in a football video sequence. In order to track better players and ball I need to estimate the homography between consecutive frames. I am doing this project in Matlab.
I am able to find enough corresponding lines between frames but it seems to me that the resulting homography isn't correct.

I start from the following situation, where I have these two processed images (1280x720 px) with corresponding lines:
[image 1](http://i61.tinypic.com/25exsee.jpg) and [image 2](http://i62.tinypic.com/33uwiur.jpg).

Lines derive from the Hough transform and are of the form `cross(P1, P2)`, where P(i) is `[x y 1]'`, with 0 < x,y < 1 (devided by the image width and height). Lines are normalized too, devided by the third component).

Before lines normalization (just after cross product) I have:

Lines from frame 1 (one line per row).

`[ -0.9986   -0.2992    0.6792
   -0.9986   -0.4305    0.5686
   -0.8000   -0.4500    0.3613
   -0.9986   -0.1609    0.7890
   -0.9986   -0.0344    0.9074
   -0.2500   -0.2164    0.0546]`

These are lines from frame 2:

`[-0.9986   -0.2984    0.6760
  -0.9986   -0.4313    0.5678
  -0.7903   -0.4523    0.3587
  -0.9986   -0.1609    0.7890
  -0.9986   -0.0391    0.9066
  -0.2486   -0.2148    0.0539]`

After normalization for each mathching line (in this case all rows correspond) I create matrix A(j)
`[-u 0 u*x -v 0 v*x -1 0 x];
 [0 -u u*y 0 -v v*y 0 -1 y];`
where line(j)_1 is `[x y 1]'` and line(j)_2 is `[u v 1]'`. Then I form the entire matrix A and calculate SVD
`[~,~,V] = svd(A);`. Rearranging the last column of V as a 3x3 matrix will give H as:

`[0.4234    0.0024   -0.3962
 -0.3750   -0.0030    0.3503
  0.4622    0.0029   -0.4322]`

This homography matrix works quite well for the parallel lines above and the vanishing point (intersection of those lines) but it does a terrible job elsewhere. For example one vanishing point is in unscaled coordinates (1194.2, -607.4), it is supposed to stay there and in fact will be mapped few pixel around (5~10px). But if I take a random point in (300, 300) will go to (1174.1, -582.7)!

I can't see if I did some big mistake or it is because the noise in the measurements. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you computed a homography mapping lines to lines. If you want the corresponding pointwise homography you need to invert and transpose it. See, for example, Chapter 1.3.1 of Hartley and Zisserman's "Multiple View Geometry".

Comment: I followed this paper [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDoQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F228541275_Combing_Line_and_Point_Correspondences_to_Calculate_Homographies_with_Applications_in_Hockey_Rink_Registration%2Flinks%2F004635231dac2c7962000000&ei=5iKCVJLkN4yVav-GgcgN&usg=AFQjCNHbz5XNYoitRmWANCk5yidpSRn0Gw&sig2=KkyU5qARbTEOdE0Qqm2oKA&bvm=bv.80642063,d.d2s) where the author combines point and lines in the DLT procedure.

Comment: Yep, see Section 5.2 of that paper: notice the difference in the expressions of the symmetric transfer error for points and lines?

Comment: Ok, but I didn't do RANSAC nor I calculated the transfer error. I found lines first, then I established correspondences (and they are correct). I fourmulated _A(j)_ as suggested in expression (10) and then I calculated the SVD.
Do you think there are conceptual mistakes or it is just because of noise?

Comment: I believe your mistake is applying to points a homography that's computd for lines.

Answer (score 1):

From the images you posted, it looks like that the lines you are considering are all parallel to each other in the scene.  Then the problem is ill-posed because there are an infinite amount of homographies which explain the resulting correspondences.  Try adding to your correspondences lines which have other directions.

Comment: Thank you. Investigating now a bit more deeply I found on [Guerrero J.J., Sagues C.](https://webdiis.unizar.es/~csagues/publicaciones/03IbPRIA-cp.pdf) that: "_A corresponding point or line gives two linear equations in terms of the elements of the homography. Thus, four corresponding lines assure a unique solution for T21,_ ___if no three of them are parallel___"

Comment: Is the fact that all lines are supposed to be equally spaced be useful in any way?

Comment: Yes, I guess it could constrain the solution a bit more, but not enough.  You would still have an infinite amount of homographies which map these lines to lines parallel to each other and equally spaced.